# Terminating a program if it finds a nonprintable character in a file in java

Tags: java

So, I am trying to read a ASCII raw file in as a String in java and then turning into a char array. So for example it should be able to read "ab" since ASCII values for those are 96 and 97. However, I want the program to end if the file has an ASCII value that is not 32 - 126 and is null.

So far I have this:

```
try {
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileArg));

    while(inputFile.hasNext() && inputFile != null){

        inputString += inputFile.next();
    }

    char inputArray[] = inputString.toCharArray();

    for(int a = 0; a < inputString.length(); a++){
        if((int)inputArray[a] < 32 && (int)inputArray[a] > 126){
            System.out.println("Invalid character found. "
                    + "The program will now terminate");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @immibis Like is there anyway to get this to work so that when a file has ASCII values 32 and below and 126 and above (the nonprintable characters) the program ends?

Comment: If that's your question, then the answer is "yes".

Comment: @immibis Can you help please?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Replacing your existing question with a new question is an incorrect use of Stack Overflow, as it invalidates all existing answers.

Comment: Regarding your new question, use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` to avoid splitting on spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an OR `||` instead of an AND `&&` when you are checking if the character is out of range. A character can't be both below AND above your limits.

Change to

```
if ((int)inputArray[a] < 32 || (int)inputArray[a] > 126)
```

Update: In order to input the whitespace characters also, use `nextLine` and `hasNextLine` instead of `next`. By default, `next` skips over whitespace.

Comment: I fixed that. However, now I am getting a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: I took out the inputFile != null part away and the error went away, but I still need the program to end if there is nothing in the file.

Comment: Just do `if (inputString.length() == 0) System.exit(0);`

Comment: Okay I fixed that. I have another issue if you could help. When I use the hasNext() it puts all the text together there is no spacing between. For example, if I have a sentence like this: "I love cookies". It will print is "Ilovecookies".

Comment: That's because `next` by default looks for the next non-whitespace character. To fix that, do `inputFile.useDelimiter("\\Z")` so that `next` will advance all the way to the end of the file.

Comment: That doesn't work. It reads that as a special character and terminates the program...

Comment: That's because newline characters are also special characters. You should use `nextLine` and `hasNextLine` then and not use the delimiter I said.

Comment: I don't want a new line. All I want is spacing between words. I updated my code. I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Sorry is there a way to change it back? I am new to these forums.

Comment: No worries, Vulcan fixed it. Yes, there is a rollback button if you look at the edit history.

Comment: If your question is answered, please select the check mark beside my answer so that others will know.

Comment: I have another doubt about this specific program. What is an end of file marker in a text file and how do we ensure that it is read?

Comment: There is no such thing as an end of file marker, only an end of line marker (the newline character ie the "Enter" key). The `\Z` thing is just a regex trick that represents the end of a string. Files end with a newline character. Using `nextLine` returns the string in the file up until the next newline character and then consumes the newline character. `hasNextLine` looks to see if there is another newline character in the file. What you are doing now is guaranteed to read the entire file, skipping over newline characters.